# return value after window closes WPF-MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am having a User Control which contains only one textbox and save button. I am showing this user control as Dialog window. After user enter comments in textbox and click on save button, I am closing the dialog window.

I am succesful doing this. My issue is I want to pass the textbox value to the main window. How can I pass this ? Here is my Code

//Showing the Window

```
 var window = new RadWindow
           {
              Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow,
              WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner
           };          
        window.Content = control;
        window.SizeToContent = true;
        window.Header = header;  
        window.ShowDialog()
```

Closing the Window in ViewModel using ICommand

```
private void SaveCommentExecute()
    {
        var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
        if (window != null)
        {
            window.Close();
        }
        // get comments and pass back to main window
    }
```

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this and NUMEROUS resources on the internet on this topic. What makes your case special??

Comment: @walther I haven't seen examples with User control

Comment: Hint : you need a dialog service if you are serious about MVVM. The model then uses the service to create the dialog and to catch the return code from showing it.

Answer (score 2):

Just expose the value through a property on your control:

```
public string TheValue
{
    get { return theTextBox.Text; }
}
```

And read it from where you show the dialog:

```
window.ShowDialog();
string value = control.TheValue;
```

(not sure why you tagged your question "MVVM", because the code you posted doesn't seem to follow the MVVM pattern)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ShowDialog`, but not any of the wonderful features it has...

In the class that shows the dialog:

```
if (window.ShowDialog() && window.DialogResult.Value == true)
{
    //Access the properties on the window that hold your data.
}
```

And then in the dialog itself:

```
if (window != null)
{
    this.DialogResult = true;
    //Set the properties to the data you want to pass back.
    window.Close();
}
```

Comment: In which viewmodel I have to do this ?

Comment: This is for Windows Forms, not WPF. And it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I modified it for WPF, but without knowing *what* data needs to be saved, I can't recommend properties to be added to the dialog. Perhaps the OP can make a property that returns the `DataContext` of the VM...

Comment: @Chatra where are your viewmodels in the first place. You have not shown any in your post.